# Regex - everything up to an optional pattern, or just everything

Tags: regex, python-re

I have the following text:
**This is a sequence of nothing. This is another**

I'm trying to write a regex that can get everything until a dot followed by space (\.\s), but if this dot followed by a space is not present in the string, then i want everything.

Example:

**This is a sequence of nothing. This is another**
*This is a sequence of nothing*

**This is a sequence of nothing this is another**
*This is a sequence of nothing this is another*

I was trying this one, but even when the string has a dot followed by a space it gets everything:

```
This is a sequence (.*)(\.\s)?
```

PS: I'm applying this regex in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
This is a sequence ((?:(?!\.\s).)*)
```

- `((?:...)*)` a group of a non-capture group, repeats any times.
- `(?!\.\s).` any character with a negative look ahead, the next two characters will never form a fullstop and a space

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/7EbMvB/1/)

Using python:

```py
import re

text = '''
This is a sequence of nothing. This is another
This is a sequence of nothing this is another
'''

result = re.findall(r'This is a sequence ((?:(?!\.\s).)*)', text)
print(result) # ['of nothing', 'of nothing this is another']
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to *exclude* the dot into your result, you could try:

```
^This is a sequence (.*?)(?:\. |$)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qqIPmc/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `This is a sequence`  - Literally "This is a sequence ".
- `(.*?)` - A capture group holding 0+ (lazy quantifier) characters upto;
- `(?:\. |$)` - A non-capture group with either a literal dot followed by a literal space **or** the end line anchor.

---

```
import re
text =  "This is a sequence of nothing. This is another"
result = re.findall(r'^This is a sequence (.*?)(?:\. |$)', text)[0]
print(result) # of nothing
```